# Laravel 5 htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have a Laravel5 project which is hosted on my server in a subfolder. I want access the project by `www.example.com/edu` I failed. I add a `.htaccess` file in root with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

But doesnot work, when I go to `www.example.com/edu/public` it works fine. How to remove public from url. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Rule:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This [link1](https://hellocoding.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/how-to-remove-public-from-url-in-laravel/) and [link2](http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/) helps you.

Hope it will work for you :)