# Apache redirection to public subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to implement a free MVC found on net. My project is stored in `http://localhost/project/`

The file and folders structure looks like:

```
/project/
         public/ (here I have index.php plus css subfolder, js etc)
         controllers/
         views/
         models/
```

File index.php (main one) is being kept in public folder.

Now, when I try to access via web: `http://localhost/project/employees` it works well and it loads employees controller... But when try to access `http://localhost/project/employees/methodtest` I get File not Found + my CSS files (stored in `public/css/main.css`) cannot be load and it show path: `http://localhost/employees/methodtest/main.css`.

I would like to be able to call `http://localhost/employees/somemethod/someparams/etc` but with my css folders/files still working.

Here is my redirection setup:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /employees/
RewriteRule ^$   public/    [L]    
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1  [L]
```

Is above clear enough in order to get some help? - Thanks!

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983870/url-rewrite-issue-not-loading-css/34984818#34984818

Comment: May be this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34871573/4198099